# How to change language for Geocoding.GetPlacemarksAsync in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I retrieve information about a place using Xamarin.Essentials.Geocoding.GetPlacemarksAsync(Location). The response is based on the language of the device (if I change the device language, I receive the response in the selected language). However, I need to obtain the response in another language. I have tried adding the following lines of code:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("uk-UA");
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("uk-UA");
```

In CultureInfo.CurrentCulture I got a new language but it hasn't worked with GetPlacemarksAsync(I continue to get response in old language that is on the device).

How can I retrieve the response in the desired language?

Comment: I'd guess you would need to use some third party API that allows you to explicitly set the locale you want the results in.